# Python Kivy: Play sound multiple times at once

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy

I am using Python Kivy for an Android Game. I want to play a sound on an event

```
sound = SoundLoader.load("sound.wav")
def onEvent():
    sound.play()
```

, and It works. But now the problem: Of course an event can, and in my case will happen again before the sound is done playing from the last event. And as the sounds are based on a play/pause idea I am getting a problem playing multiple sounds of the same object at once. That can be solved like this for first:

```
onEvent():
    SoundLoader.load("sound.wav").play()
```

As this creates a new object all the time, and so is able to play it the same time another event plays the sound. But the problem using this method is quite obvious, because the sound must be loaded everytime the event occurs, and so causes a delay until it's played.

Is there a more useful way to do this?

*{ if you don't understand what I am talking about, or just don't see the problem, feel free to ask }*

Comment: create a dictionary of sound objects and do the loading all at once in the constructor of your objects that have these sounds. When you want to play a particular sound access it via constant time access in your map object and play. ie sound_dict['hit'].play() where 'hit' is the key and the value is the SoundLoader.load("hit.wav"), or Sound object

Comment: Additionally, it is not uncommon for games to have to load data before a game starts so it makes sense to do all the initial loading of sound objects in the beginning

Comment: That would have the same effect like my first method if I understood you right.

Comment: The Clock object http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock#kivy.clock , is more suitable to use for this case

Comment: @FIns ?! I want to play sounds. The problem is, that I can't play one sound multiple times at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can workaround this by loading multiple instances of the sound.
For instance

```
sounds = [SoundLoader.load("sound.wav") for _ in range(10)]
index = 0
```

and then

```
def play():
    sounds[index].play()
    index = (index + 1) % len(sounds)
```

The more sounds you load, the more instances you can have playing at the same time (in this example 10).

Comment: Well, if this is the only solution. I mean, it's not memory friendly actually, but it should work..